# Working fine on iPhone but crashing on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, memory-leaks

I made an Ecommerce app for `iPhone` and `iPad` using objective c. The app is working fine on iPhone but crashing a lot on iPad. I am getting lot of memory warning on iPad. I tried different things to get it control but not getting any success. Apps has features like

1. As per user current location it shows the store on map view and list view.
2. During checking user can order as per his current location or can place an order for different location.
3. Add favorite product and favorite store

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong or anything I should implement to get it fixed.

Comment: sumit see the task taking most memory, I must be a memory leak, else please see the crash log.

Comment: From that information nobody can even guess what went wrong. Did you try instumenting your app and look where the memory goes to? And are you sure that it crashes because of lacking proper response to memory warnings? Do you release any memory at all?

Comment: Profile your app with instruments and just in case update the question with crash logs

Comment: The problem is nothing gets print I get the memory warning in my log and it gets crashed after few seconds of the warning. See the attached screenshot http://imgur.com/1qWQ5B6

Comment: iPad model vs iPhone model? Could explain why the iPad is getting faster crash due to memory warning. What says Instruments about Memory Leaks? Help you to find out what you didn't released. What says Instruments about Allocation ? Help you to find out where there is too much consumption, and may point out what could be allocated uselessly.

Comment: You need at least provide a fully symbolicated crash report. Receiving a lot of memory warnings also suggests you are allocating way too much memory and you should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instruments. That's actually the only device that anyone can give you. And of course be aware that if your app is in the background, crashing after a memory warning is quite normal and not something the user will even notice.